# Substitute one group with another group; Followup question

Tags: regex, notepad++, substitution

I'll be referring to this thread:
[Substitute one group with another group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69922019/substitute-one-group-with-another-group)

What I'd like to do is to put a value of P1(y) in to P4(y),
with end result: `(...) <P4 x="-0,36935" y="0,26315"/>`

[image: setting values of groups]

My previous question, being similar, seems to require a completely new approach.
And unfortunately I couldn't find a reliable solution.

Example to work on:
https://regex101.com/r/iua3p0/2

```
<P1 x="-0,36935" y="0,26315"/><P2 (...)/><P3 (..)/><P4 x="-0,36935" y="-0,40351"/>
<P1 x="4,64065" y="0,26315"/><P2 (...)/><P3 (..)/><P4 x="4,64065" y="-0,40351"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a value of  P1(y) in to P4(y) on the same line, you could use:

```
<P1[^>]*\hy="([^"]+)"[^>]*>.*?<P4[^>]*\hy="\K[^"]+(?=[^>]*>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `<P1[^>]*` Match `<P1` and optional chars other than `>`
- `\hy="` Match a space and `y="`
- `([^"]+)` Capture chars other than `"` in **group 1**
- `"[^>]*>` Match `"` and optional chars other than `>` and then match `>`
- `.*?` Match as few as possible chars
- `<P4[^>]*\hy="` Match `<P4` and optional char other than `>` and then match a space and `y="`
- `\K[^"]+` Clear the match buffer, and then match what you want to remove, in this case 1+ chars other than `"`
- `(?=[^>]*>)` Positive lookahead to assert a `>` to the right

And replace with group 1 using `$1`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yxrp2K/1).

[image]

**Note** that to not match across lines using the negated character class, you can exclude matching newlines using `[^"\r\n]` and `[^>\r\n]*`